When does Patrick Star teach the art of relaxing?
I was watching SpongeBob SquarePants with my daughter a few years ago and there was this episode where Patrick Star teaches the art of relaxing; the zen of keeping his mind blank.
I'm trying to find the episode and I can't find it. I've done some perfunctory searches but haven't found anything. I have no idea what season it was in nor do I have any recollections of other scenes.

I apologize, but as there are no question marks: what, exactly, is your question?

Sorry. I'm trying to find the episode. I edited the post to clear things up.

Episode "Stanley S. SquarePants", Season 5

Patrick: Looking for your calling, huh? (walks around Stanley) Hmmm. Mm-hmm. So, what are you good at?
Stanley: Nothing.
Patrick: Nothing at all?
Stanley: Yep.
Patrick: Interesting. Let's see how good you are at nothing.
SpongeBob: That's perfect. Patrick can do nothing better than anyone. (whispers in Stanley's ear) You'll be learning from the master.
Patrick: Come with me. First, sit down in this chair. Clear your mind. Empty it of all thoughts until you're doing abso...lute...ly... nothing. (sticks his tongue out and drools) Gah!
SpongeBob: See? Isn't he amazing?
Stanley: (monotone) Clear my mind. Do nothing. (focuses on Stanley's difficulty to do nothing) I can't do it!
Patrick: You're not worthy of instruction in the immobile arts. Leave my presence.
Stanley: Couldn't I try...?
Patrick: Good-bye! Not a word! (goes back to doing nothing) Dah!
Stanley: I can't even do nothing right.  




